# Filtering database rows with spring-data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have many columns in the database and it is senseless to do the method for each column separately. How can one method get an associative array, a column, and its value, and filter data in this array?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) or [query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example).